# Why doesn't my Spring @autowired DAO get autowired?

Tags: spring, autowired

I am trying @autowired for the first time, and failing.  I have read so many examples, and I seem to be doing everything right, but when my code hits my getLeagueDAO() method, the instance variable is set to null.

I have the following code:

```
package com.example.app.service;

@Service
public class LeagueService {

    // also tried @Autowired here, and that didn't work
    private LeagueDAO leagueDao; // = new LeagueHibernateDAO();

    public LeagueDAO getLeagueDAO() {
        return this.leagueDao;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setLeagueDAO( LeagueDAO dao ) {
        this.leagueDao = dao;
    }

    [ ... ]
```

LeagueHibernateDAO:

```
package com.example.app.dao.impl.hibernate;

import ...

public class LeagueHibernateDAO implements LeagueDAO {

    public LeagueHibernateDAO() {
        super();
    }

    [ ... ]
```

My *-servlet.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd

        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd

        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="LeagueDAO" class="com.example.app.dao.impl.hibernate.LeagueHibernateDAO" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My Spring dependencies are:

```
    ... <org.springframework.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework.version> ...


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

My unit tests don't run.  My app doesn't run.  All because leagueDao isn't being set in LeagueService.  Why isn't it getting wired?

**My Full Solution**

For the benefit of anyone who comes along with similar issues...

1) It's clear I didn't know how to write a test of autowired code.  The accepted answer provides a working example of how to do this.

2) It appears that with autowiring, it's essentially all-or-nothing.  I had already created an application and wanted to go back and autowire it.  So I thought I would start small and autowire the LeagueDAO into the LeagueService.  However, because the LeagueServiceTest didn't autowire LeagueService, it wouldn't wire up references to LeagueDAO.  Once I properly autowired each step in the chain, everything worked.

So when I tried to run my application, even though my tests now worked, my application again was not autowiring.  To fix things, I finally realized I had to fully autowire another chain.  In this case, I already had LeagueDAO plugged into LeagueService.  The problem was that LeagueService is invoked by a controller, which was simply instantiating the LeagueService class by invoking the constructor.  When I autowired LeagueService into the controller, everything began to work.

I have read so much stuff on this, and if that's explained anywhere, it wasn't explained in a way that was clear to me.  Arrrgh.

Comment: Can I see you `LeagueHibernateDAO` code?

Comment: There ya go!  Right after the service class.

Comment: What's the package of LeagueService?

Comment: Added to the code sample:  It's com.example.app.service.

Comment: How does the the spring configuration get loaded in your unit tests?

Comment: I actually wanted to ask that, but thought that was too many questions.  How SHOULD it get loaded?  Regardless, if I build the app and deploy it, it fails then with the same problem:  null reference to the DAO.

Comment: a>are any errors reported on the console? b> Are you sure you're not compiling with debug symbols off?

Comment: a) No errors I can find, other than the null pointer exceptions.  b) I'm able to debug the code, so symbols are on.  Or do you mean debug logging?

Comment: At this point, LeagueDAOTest is autowired and working properly.  LeagueServiceTest instantiates LeagueService, and LeagueService attempts to autowire LeagueDAO, but that autowiring fails (the reference is simply null.)  This is absolutely infuriating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works

**Unit Test**

```
package com.example.app.service;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.*;

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations={"/springcontext.xml"})
    public class TestLeagueService {

        @Autowired
        LeagueService service;

        @Test
        public void test() {
            assertNotNull(service.getLeagueDAO()); 
        }

    }
```

**DAO**

```
package com.example.app.dao.impl.hibernate;

public interface LeagueDAO {

}
```

**Dao Impl**

```
package com.example.app.dao.impl.hibernate;

public class LeagueHibernateDAO implements LeagueDAO {


    public LeagueHibernateDAO() {
        super();
    }
}
```

**Spring Context**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

     <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example"/>


    <bean id="LeagueDAO" class="com.example.app.dao.impl.hibernate.LeagueHibernateDAO" />
    <bean id="LeagueService" class="com.example.app.service.LeagueService" />


</beans>
```

Comment: I added the Spring unit test stuff and after a few stumbles, that appears to work.  However, it still doesn't autowire the DAO reference.  My tests continue to fail with a null pointer.  (Do I really need to have my DAO interfaces in the same package as the implementation?)

Comment: @Marvo No you can place your Intefaces wherever you want. For my simple test it was simply easier to place it into the same package as the implementation.

Comment: Where are you putting the springcontext.xml file?  I've tried a few locations.  I thought I had it working in WEB-INF and specifying     @ContextConfiguration(locations={"WEB-INF/springcontext.xml"}) (with or without a preceding slash) but I'm getting "cannot be opened because it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Marvo Spring config files are usually placed somewhere within the classpath i.e. for web applications `WEB-INF/classes`. See [Common Webapp Configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#web-integration-common) for how to integrate the Springframework in Webapplications.

Comment: If you use the `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` to load your application context spring per default tries load the context configuration from `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`.

Comment: What I've discovered and read, @ContextConfiguration(location="xxx") will try to load, for tests, from src/test/resources.  It will prefix with the package for the test, so if you want a common context file, put it right in resource, and prefix with a slash (/).  That was not easy to figure out.  (I imagine the reason is so that you can create custom configurations for each test, allowing you to inject various mocks for each situation.)

Comment: I did finally get an example running.  But my actual application continues to fail to autowire anything.

Comment: Your example gave me enough working code to help me figure out what I needed.  Thanks so very much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if the Spring container is starting when you start the app? It could be an issue with your `web.xml` configuration.

Comment: I did want to point out that while my web.xml was correct, what I had gotten all confused was how Tomcat is "properly" installed on a Mac.  I'd forgotten it goes into /Library and re-installed it into ~/Servers for my convenience.  The side effect was that the scripts run from ~/Servers/tomcat/bin would work -- but they'd actually be running the code in /Library.  Therefore the ~/Servers/tomcat/logs directory didn't have any logs in it, leaving me scratching my head.  So you kinda solved a problem I didn't ask about.  =)